# Is it save to expose the gRPC ProtoReflectionService?

Tags: security, grpc, grpc-java

The Java gRPC implementation (and probably other languages as well) comes with the ProtoReflectionService that exposes the methods a specific gRPC service offers and the request/response messages they expect or return.

I'd like to expose one of my services to the public internet. I'm wondering, if I need to remove the ProtoReflectionService from that gRPC service for security or other reasons?

Comment: Questions that solicit opinions are discouraged on stack overflow. Do the benefits to you of service|method discovery outweigh the disadvantages? Discovery primarily saves explicitly referencing the protobuf source. If your service endpoints and the protobuf sources are public, there's negligible benefit in not enabling service|method reflection.

Comment: This could definitely become another attack surface.